# Firebase - query on nested key?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running an Android app that handles some data on `Events` and `Users` who have been invited to them. I have a page that needs to show all the events that a user has been invited to, but I'm relatively new to Firebase and I'm not sure how the query syntax would work for my current data structure.

An example of my data-structure (with dummy keys) can be seen below:

```
events
    event1_key
        eventName: "test event"
        eventAdmin: "userAdmin"
        eventInvites
            user1_key
                attending: true
                responseTimestamp: 1525416294951
            user2_key
                //...
    event2_key
        //...
        eventInvites
            user2_key
                //...
            user3_key
                //...
```

So using this example, if I was looking for all the events that `user1_key` had been invited to, the query should only return the `event1_key` record, because that one has a nested `eventInvite` for `user1_key`.

If I'm running that query in Java for Android Studio, does anybody know what it should look like?

Comment: Have tried my solution below?

Comment: @AlexMamo I got this working, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replicate your data in another node in this case. Right now, you have a single node which keeps all the events (i.e. `events` node). I would suggest your create a separate table (i.e. separate node) for users as well.

That node structure might look like the following.

```
users 
    user1_key
        events1_key
        events2_key
        ... 
    user2_key
        events5_key
        events2_key
        ....
    ....
```

I this way you will not require any nested lookup. Just replicate the data here in this node as well when you are inserting the data under events node.

Hope that helps!

**Update**

If you are considering replicating your table, then the check for user is attending an event will be fairly simple like the following.

```
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        boolean attending = false; 
        for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(eventSnapshot.getKey().equals(THE_DESIRED_EVENT)) {
                attending = true; 
                break;
            }
        }

        if(attending) doSomethingAsUserIsFoundToBeAttendingTheEvent();
        else userIsNotAttending();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The code is not tested, I just have the pseudo implementation. Please modify as per your need.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this! I will look into doing this. In the case you've outlined here, what would the query be to see if `user1_key`'s node contained `event1_key`?

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. I'll give it a run and mark the answer right if it flies!

Comment: Great, please let me know if you face any other difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, I recommend add another node in your database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- userEvents
           |
           --- user1_key
                 |
                 --- event1_key: true
                 |
                 --- event2_key: true
```

In this way you'll be able to read all your events that correspond to a particular user at once without the need to download the enitire `events` object. To get those ids, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userKeyRef = rootRef.child("userEvents").child(userKey);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String eventKey = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", eventKey);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```